# Listing Absolute Paths of Files in Terminal w/more than 255 Characters

Tags: terminal, find, applescript, posix

I have a two part problem:

Part 1 (Terminal) - I'm working in a Mac environment that archives to a Windows-based system so I need to detect path lengths of 255 so I can alter those files before archive. I've seen many solutions on StackOverflow concerning filename length, but I need absolute path length. I happened upon this script and it's close:

```
sudo find . -name \* -type f | perl -ne 's/(.*)/print length($1), " $1\n" if (length($1)>254)/e' | sort -n
```

The problem is that I'm not seeing the absolute path length, I'm only seeing the path length from the current directory. Is there a way I can search for files recursively within the current directory while still showing the absolute path of all listed files?

Part 2 (Applescript) - Once part one is working correctly in Terminal I'm looking to automate the process a bit. Preferably I'd like to create an Applescript that when the folder is highlighted in Finder, I can run the command and the Terminal will pop up and run the command and list. This is what I have so far:

```
tell application "Finder" to set theSel to selection
tell application "Terminal" 
set theFol to POSIX path of ((item 1 of theSel) as text)    
if (count of windows) is not 0 then 
    set shell to do script "cd " & quoted form of theFol in window 1        
do script "find . -name \\* -type f | perl -ne 's/(.*)/print length($1), \" $1\\n\" if (length($1)>254)/e''" in shell       
end if
activate
end tell
```

The problem is that when I run this applescript, the command starts to go through the motions but then gets stuck and all I see is

```
>
```

I have to ctrl+c out to continue using the Terminal window.

Does anyone know what flag I'm missing in the Terminal command? I'm also open to completely a different method of retrieving and listing the number of characters and absolute path of files that are 255 characters or more for a highlighted directory.

Comment: Do you need to use the terminal? what is the purpose of that? What is the true result you're require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what value you're getting out of using the Terminal in this situation so here is a solution I've added without it.

```
on run
    set longPaths to {}
    tell application "Finder" to set theSel to selection
    repeat with aFile in theSel
        set aFile to aFile as string
        set pathLength to count of characters in aFile
        if pathLength > 255 then
            set end of longPaths to aFile
        end if
    end repeat

    if longPaths is not equal to {} then
        -- do something with your list of long paths, write them to a text file or whatever you want
        set pathToYourTextFile to (path to desktop folder as string)&"SampleTextFile.txt"
        set tFile to open for access file (pathToYourTextFile as string) with write permission
        repeat with filePath in longPaths
            write (filePath & return as string) to tFile starting at eof
        end repeat
        close access tFile
    end if
end run
```

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance of Applescript in general (the above is extremely helpful), but what would be the easiest way to write the list to a text file located on the Desktop?

Comment: @AlexNoble - I updated the code above to reflect the output to a text file

Comment: So I just noticed that this isn't reading recursively through the directories, it's only reading the current directory selected. Do you know a way to get it to read through all subdirectories of the selection as well? Really really appreciate everything you've done with this.

Comment: @AlexNoble - You're going to have to build your own recursion handler. Here is an example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896175/applescript-processing-files-in-folders-recursively) of one that can be found on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the path of the folder into the `find` command instead of use of the `cd command`.

Like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFol to item 1 of (get selection)
    if class of theFol is not folder then return -- not a folder
end tell
set f to quoted form of POSIX path of (theFol as text)

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "find " & f & " -name \\* -type f | perl -ne 'print length($_), \" $_\",  if length($_)>255'" -- (>255 characters), because the $_ variable contains a newline
    activate
end tell
```

---

Info of the `do script` command in your AppleScript: your command stuck in the Terminal, because you put two simple quote character at the end of the `perl` command.