# Applescript - Recursively searching through directories

Tags: macos, recursion, applescript

I have a script that was generously created by another user here, but I've found that it doesn't read recursively through directories. The goal of the script is to read through all sub directories of a directory selected in the Finder, and to write out any absolute paths of files that are 255 characters or longer (path not filename). This is to find files with absolute path lengths that are too long on OSX for a Windows machine with the 255 character path limit, before transferring them from one to the other.

I've tried referencing this post to make it recursive but to no avail as the approach here appears quite different: [AppleScript Processing Files in Folders recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896175/applescript-processing-files-in-folders-recursively)

```
on run
set longPaths to {}
tell application "Finder" to set theSel to selection
repeat with aFile in theSel
    set aFile to aFile as string
    set pathLength to count of characters in aFile
    if pathLength > 255 then
        set end of longPaths to aFile
    end if
end repeat

if longPaths is not equal to {} then
    -- do something with your list of long paths, write them to a text file or whatever you want
    set pathToYourTextFile to (path to desktop folder as string)&"SampleTextFile.txt"
    set tFile to open for access file (pathToYourTextFile as string) with write permission
    repeat with filePath in longPaths
        write (filePath & return as string) to tFile starting at eof
    end repeat
    close access tFile
end if
end run
```

Does anyone know the best way to add a recursive element to this script so that theSel includes all files in the subdirectories of the selected directory?

Comment: What is the result you're getting now? Please add an example to your question.

Comment: Right now, the script will only read the files or folders highlighted in Finder. If the file or directory has an absolute path longer than 255 characters, it writes that path to a text file on the Desktop called "SmpleTextFile.txt".

So the problem is that the "set theSel to selection" is only those items highlighted in the Finder, whereas I'm looking for a way for the selection to include all files in a selected directory (including subdirectories).

Comment: Check my answer in your "**Listing absolute paths ...**" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script which read recursively through directories:

```
property theOpenFile : missing value

tell application "Finder" to set theSel to selection
if theSel is not {} then
    set pathToYourTextFile to (path to desktop folder as string) & "SampleTextFile2.txt"
    set theOpenFile to open for access file (pathToYourTextFile as string) with write permission
    repeat with aItem in theSel
        tell application "Finder" to class of aItem is folder
        if the result then my getFilesIn(aItem) -- aItem is a folder
    end repeat
    close access theOpenFile
end if

on getFilesIn(thisFolder)
    tell application "Finder" to set theseFiles to files of thisFolder as alias list
    repeat with thisFile in theseFiles
        set f to thisFile as string
        set pathLength to length of f
        if pathLength > 255 then my writeToFile(f)
    end repeat
    tell application "Finder" to set theseSubFolders to folders of thisFolder
    repeat with tSubF in theseSubFolders
        my getFilesIn(tSubF) -- call this handler (recursively through this folder)
    end repeat
end getFilesIn

on writeToFile(t)
    write (t & return) to theOpenFile starting at eof
end writeToFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to set theSel to every file in (get entire contents of selection)
```

Or something like that.  Sorry, I am without a Mac to test the precise code.  Whenever you ask for `entire contents`, you get everything in all subfolders of your chosen folder.

Comment: Unforunately this doesn't work, I get: "Finder got an error: Can’t get entire contents of selection." number -1728 from entire contents of selection